# How to override the slide effect to dissolve effect in JQuery Mobile using CSS3 feautures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I need to override the  default slide effect to dissolve effect.

When `changePage` function is called I need to slowly dissolve the current page to new page.

I tried with following CSS

```
@keyframes dissolve {
    0% { opacity:1; }
    5% { opacity:0.9;}
    15% { opacity:0.7;}
    25% { opacity:0.5;}
    35% { opacity:0.3;}
    45% { opacity:0;}
    55% { opacity:0.2;}
    65% { opacity:0.4;}
    75% { opacity:0.6;}
    85% { opacity:0.8;}
    95% { opacity:0.9;}
    100% { opacity:1;}
}
.in, .out, .slide.in, .slide.out, .slide.out.reverse, .slide.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: dissolve;
    -moz-animation-name: dissolve;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 350ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 350ms

}
```

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justin_j/xMDaY/2/) with above css.

The page transistion is not smooth with above code.

How to correct page transistion to run smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  obtained dissolve effect by css using keyframes and overriding the **CSS** of jQuery Mobile.

Please add `@-webkit-keyframes` ,`@-moz-keyframes`, and `@-o-keyframes` in **CSS** like `@keyframes` added below.

```
@keyframes dissolve-out {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    20% { opacity: 0.5; }
    40% { opacity: 0.2; }
    60% { opacity: 0; }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes dissolve-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    20% { opacity: 0; }
    40% { opacity: 0; }
    60% { opacity: 0.2; }
    80% { opacity: 0.6; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.slideup.in, .slide.in, .slide.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation: dissolve-in;
    -moz-animation: dissolve-in;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s !important;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s !important;
}
.slide.out, .slide.out.reverse {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -webkit-animation: dissolve-out;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-animation: dissolve-out;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s !important;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s !important;
}
```

Please see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xMDaY/4/).

Above **CSS** will give you a dissolve effect with overriding the default slide effect of page transistion in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

you need also vendor prefixes in @keyframes: @-webkit-keyframes and so on ..

Comment: It's not vendor prefix problem. I already given it as `@-moz-keyframes` and `@-webkit-keyframes`. It's jquery mobile transistion issue.